# Send Firefox crash reports to Mozilla, not to Apple

Tags: macos, firefox, crash

On occasion Firefox will crash on my Mac and bring up a prompt asking if I'd like to send the crash report to Apple. I never want to send the report to Apple, but I wouldn't mind if it was sent to the Firefox developers.  How can I change the destination of crash reports?

Answer (score 2):

The system crash reports by default will always go to Apple - however depending on the version of Firefox you're running ([3 or later](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Breakpad)) Firefox will see that it crashed last time and sent the crash reports to them. You'll see a second program open called Mozilla Crash Reporter at times when it asks for more details.

Comment: That answers sending to Apple part of the question. Still, I don't see Mozilla Crash Reporter program on a crash.